# how to change chart on click?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I have couple buttons which displays data by hours and days.Right now I have chart only with hours. How to add another chart with data and display it on click?

```
export const chartInitialize = (parent: any) => {
const canvas: any = document.getElementById("chart")
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

chartHour = new Chart(ctx, {
type: "line",
data: {
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "HourStamp",
      backgroundColor: createGradientLineColor(ctx, "#5f8fd8"),
      borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
      data: getRandomData(0, 116),
    },
  ],
},
options: {
  title: {
    display: true,
    fontFamily: "'Montserrat', sans-serif",
  },
  legend: {
    display: false,
  },

 },
})
}
```

Comment: you can try to add it in the page and toggle his visibility via click event on something.

Comment: You're missing a lot of code here, e.g. where is `getRandomData()` method and where is `createGradientLineColor()` method?

Comment: @Viqas that functions not important , chart can work without them . The main problem  how to pass data to the chart on click

Comment: In just trying to recreate the issue from your code and not able to. Could you reproduce your issue in SlackBlitz?